# An alternative for 'conceited' concerning merely wealth

Tags: single-word-requests

What would one call a person that is not conceited, meaning he or she is not concerned about her reputation, but teaches his or her children that wealth and security are the primary objectives of life and quite likes to talk about this wealth he or she possesses?

Furthermore, they may be quite patronising, yet never "peacocky".

Comment: A wealth conscious person.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you will accept a hyphenated compound, I nominate *purse-proud:*

> Proud or arrogant on account of one’s wealth; (also) having an inflated regard for wealth. [OED]
>
> Proud because of one’s wealth especially in the absence of other distinctions.  [[Merriam-Webster]](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/purse-proud)

It is [a little old-fashioned](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=purse-proud&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3), but some of us positively and perversely relish that in a word.

Comment: This! I didn't know this term, but it instantly sounded like the one to go for. You had me at old-fashioned :)

Answer (score 4):

Such a person can be said to be "avaricious", that is to say, characterised by [avarice](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/avarice).

> **noun**
>
> 1: insatiable greed for riches; inordinate, miserly desire to gain and hoard wealth.
>
> *www.dictionary.com*

Answer (score 3):

Here are a few:

- acquisitive,
- materialistic,
- mercenary (*when used as an adjective*),
- money-grubbing (*informal*)

There could be others, can't think of them right now.